# How to make buttons move on the server form when I switch between clients windows?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, tcpclient

I have a TCP/IP model that represents client and Server projects. My Client project has a button which I can move using AWDS letters. When I move the Location of the client Form button is serialized to bytes and sends to the server. It deserialize it and creates the same button in its form with the same location. However, when I have only one client everything is working fine but when I have two then the second button is not moving anymore.

here is my server code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpListener listener;
        NetworkStream stream;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ServerStart();
        }

        private async void ServerStart()
        {
            IPAddress localaddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(55555);
            try
            {
                listener = new TcpListener(localaddr, port);
                listener.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    var client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
                    await Task.Run(() => ReceiveInfo(client));
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException) { }

        }

        private  void ReceiveInfo(TcpClient client)
        {
           
            stream = client.GetStream();
            Button b = new Button() { Width = 100 };
            b.Text = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            b.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { this.Controls.Add(b); }));
            }


             Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 try
                 {
                     while (true)
                     {
                         do
                         {
                             BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                             Point p = (Point)bf.Deserialize(stream);
                             b.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { b.Location = p; }));
                         }
                         while (stream.DataAvailable);
                     }
                 }
                 catch (Exception) { }
             });


        }

    }
```

here is my client code

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TcpClient client;
        NetworkStream stream;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect("127.0.0.1", 55555);
            stream = client.GetStream();
        }

        private async Task SendMessage()
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[50];
            Point point = b.Location;
            try
            {
                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                        bf.Serialize(ms, point);
                        data = ms.ToArray();
                }
                await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            catch (SocketException exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
        }


        private async void b_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.A:
                    b.Location = new Point(b.Location.X - 1, b.Location.Y);
                    break;
                case Keys.D:
                    b.Location = new Point(b.Location.X + 1, b.Location.Y);
                    break;
                case Keys.W:
                    b.Location = new Point(b.Location.X, b.Location.Y - 1);
                    break;
                case Keys.S:
                    b.Location = new Point(b.Location.X, b.Location.Y + 1);
                    break;
             
            }
            await SendMessage();
        }

       
    }
```

Comment: What's the use of the byte array in the server code? Also, print something on console when exceptions happen. Silent failure is never a good idea.

Comment: You already have try catch SocketException. Print something in there instead of just catching.

Comment: I have added but there is not exception. In the debug mode I saw thread... exited....

Comment: The do loop in the while true in the server is suspicious. It's going to loop like crazy.